# Sql query column unknown in where of casted as field

Tags: mysql, sql, casting

This query is not working

```
 SELECT CAST(o.total as SIGNED INTEGER) as yakk 
 FROM `order` o   
 WHERE yakk  = '51' ORDER BY `o`.`order_id` DESC  limit 0, 50
```

it says yakk column is uknown while if I remove where clause it works and shows the column

Answer (score 2):

You can't use alias in where condition you must repeat the code 
(and if you cast to integer then use an int for compare)

```
SELECT CAST(o.total as SIGNED INTEGER) as yakk 
FROM `order` o   
WHERE CAST(o.total as SIGNED INTEGER)  = 51 ORDER BY `o`.`order_id` DESC  limit 0, 50
```

The alias created for select are not available for where because the where condition is evaluted  before the select clause

Comment: Or instead of where use having plus one